# Are "struct" and "class" keywords the same when forward declaring?

Tags: c++, class, forward-declaration

In the past I've been able to forward declare a class as a struct and vice-versa, or to declare the type like in C, like:

```
void function(struct Foo* arg);
void function(class Foo* arg);
```

I thought they were the same thing for the purposes of this or forward declaring because I've heard many times that the only difference between a struct and class is the default access specifiers (struct being public default while class is private).

I've changed one word in a class of mine from "struct" to "class" and for the first time I've seen that it breaks my code, the linker says that it can't find a variable of that type that's defined somewhere. Is this not allowed to mix "struct" and "class" in this way?

Answer (score -3):

You sometimes get away with it. And often you don't.

struct, class and namespace are *NOT* the same. You absolutely *DO* need to use the correct keyword when forward declaring.

Much to my annoyance, because there's no legal way to forward declare a nested class or struct.

Comment: The OP didn't ask about namespace, and struct/class *are the same*. Visual Studio may not think so, but the C++ standard does. And forward-declaring nested types has nothing to do with whether `struct` or `class` is the same.

Comment: @NicolBolas Some programmers seem to think that because their compiler doesn't mark class, struct and namespace as different types, that they're allowed to forward declare nested classes as a class in a namespace. They are wrong but they think "well the compiler allows it it must be OK!"

Comment: @NicolBolas Also even if the standard claims they're equivalent at least one compiler disagrees and in my opinion using the wrong keyword in a forward declaration is *just sloppy* in any case.

Comment: "*Some programmers seem to think that because their compiler doesn't mark class, struct and namespace as different types, that they're allowed to forward declare nested classes as a class in a namespace.*" No programmer thinks that. And no compiler allows you to forward declare a nested class as a class in a namespace. And again, the OP didn't mention namespaces, so I have no idea why you even brought them up.

Comment: "*Also even if the standard claims they're equivalent at least one compiler disagrees*" ... so what? That doesn't make them right. You can disagree on whether or not it's OK to steal something, but that's not going to be an effective defense at trial.